# How to get label value in gridview c# from code behind

Tags: c#, gridview

I have changed label text by jquery, now I can not get its value from code behind.

(Net payable is that label)

[image]

I used below code:-

```
      Label lbl = gvViewSalarySheet.Rows[i].FindControl("lblNetPayable") as Label;
      string l4 = lbl.Text;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it because jquery is a client side javascript library and code behind is server side. You have changed the label in client side. Server has no information about client side modifications unless you inform server. You can use ajax to inform server from client side modifications.

Comment: It's because `Textbox` is a type of input. Server gets informed for any type of inputs.

Comment: modify the textbox to look like label, i did that , or hard way, you can keep a hidden field for tracking the new value

Comment: k, i want to make this textbox read only but the problem is that m not getting its value from code behind

Comment: i have lots of records and i need the same number of hidden fields, right?